# Inverse quantum Fourier transformation (QFT) on a 4 qubit state

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform

I'm looking to calculate explicitly the inverse QFT acting on a four qubit state. Would the inverse just be calculated as the following:

\begin{equation}\label{QFTProduct}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \left( |0> + e^{-2\pi i (0.j_{n})} |1>\right) \otimes ... \otimes \left( |0> + e^{-2\pi i (0.j_{2}j_{3}...j_{n})} |1> \right) \left( |0> + e^{-2\pi i (0.j_{1}j_{2}...j_{n})} |1> \right)
\end{equation}

Take $N=2^{n}$, where $n$ is some integer, and the basis $|0>,...,|2^{n}-1>$ is the computational basis for an n qubit quantum computer.

So for example, would the inverse QFT of the state $|1010>$ read

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4}(|0> + |1>)(|0>-|1>)(|0>-i|1>)(|0>+e^{-5\pi i /4}|1>)
\end{equation}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.